# Which IP address am I using to call an external API?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a PHP script that I use to geocode addresses using the Google Geocode API. This works well on my test server. I use the URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=SECRET&address=ADDRESS&sensor=false
```

But when deployed to the production server, I get this error message:

```
{ "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }
```

The server has multiple IP addresses, and I do not know the IP range or all of the IP addresses, and therefore, I am unable to add them in [Google's API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
It is **not the public IP address** of the server.

So how do I find out which IP address my production server is using for calling the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem, however, it does not really answer my original question, which I will leave open.

It is possible to add the `userIp`-parameter, according to some [well-hidden Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#cappingusage).

So I successfully used the call

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=SECRET&address=ADDRESS&sensor=false&userIp=11.22.33.44
```

where the IP address was one of the allowed IP-addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address of the server which is being used on external request can be found by making a HTTP request to http://ip.appspot.com/

PHP code:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://ip.appspot.com/');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have also tried that before asking the question, but this does not give the correct IP address either. I guess the server is set up so it routes to Google's differently than to eg. http://ip.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of the server can be retrieved from `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

You can try emailing the IP address of the server to yourself when you see the error message.

More info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: No, this is unfortunately not the IP address I'm using to make the call.

The `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` contains the server's IP address used for the HTTP connection that the user establishes when calling the PHP script, not the IP address used for the connection to Google Geocode API.